# With shell, how to extract (to separate variables) values that are surrounded by "=" and space?

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix

For example, I have a string `/something an-arg=some-value another-arg=another-value`.

What would be the most straightforward way to extract `an-arg`'s value to a variable and `another-arg`'s value to another variable?

To better exemplify, this is what I need to happen:

```
STRING="/something an-arg=some-value another-arg=another-value"
AN_ARG=... # <-- do some magic here to extract an-arg's value
ANOTHER_ARG=... # <-- do some magic here to extract another-arg's value
echo $AN_ARG # should print `some-value`
echo $ANOTHER_ARG # should print `another-value`
```

So I was looking for a simple/straightforward way to do this, I tried:

```
ARG_NAME="an-arg="
AN_ARG=${STRING#*$ARG_NAME}
```

But the problem with this solution is that it will print everything that comes after `an-arg`, including the second argument's name and its value, eg `some-value another-arg=another-value`.

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle `STRING='var="two words" var2="more words"'`?

Comment: BTW, it's bad form to use all-caps names for your own variables; changes to variables with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed not to have unwanted side effects on shell- or OS-provided tools. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html establishing that guideline (the standard document linked is labeled "environment variables", but setting a regular variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the convention applies to both types).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The example was a bit misleading indeed, the argument values will always be one word (in the sense they will never be a string with spaces).

Comment: ...really, the _best_ way to do this would be to set up an associative array -- that way `string="/something LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/evil.so"` can't be used to hack your box. I've also sometimes put a constant prefix on generated variable names for the same reason; `my_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is harmless, after all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting data set arbitrary variables incurs substantial security risks. You should either prefix your generated variables (with a prefix having at least one lower-case character to keep the generated variables in the namespace POSIX reserves for application use), or put them in an associative array; the first example below does the latter.

---

#### Generating An Associative Array

As you can see at https://ideone.com/cKcMSM --

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- specifically, bash 4.0 or newer; NOT /bin/sh

declare -A vars=( )

re='^([^=]* )?([[:alpha:]_-][[:alnum:]_-]+)=([^[:space:]]+)( (.*))?$'
string="/something an-arg=some-value another-arg=another-value third-arg=three"
while [[ $string =~ $re ]]; do : "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
  string=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
  vars[${BASH_REMATCH[2]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
done

declare -p vars # print the variables we extracted
```

...correctly emits:

```
declare -A vars=([another-arg]="another-value" [an-arg]="some-value" [third-arg]="three" )
```

...so you can refer to `${vars[an-arg]}`, `${vars[another-arg]}` or `${vars[third-arg]}`.

This avoids faults in the original proposal whereby a string could set variables with meanings to the system -- changing `PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD`, or other security-sensitive values.

---

#### Generating Prefixed Names

To do it the other way might look like:

```
while [[ $string =~ $re ]]; do : "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
  string=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
  declare -n _newVar="var_${BASH_REMATCH[2]//-/_}" || continue
  _newVar=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  unset -n _newVar
  declare -p "var_${BASH_REMATCH[2]//-/_}"
done
```

...which work as you can see at https://ideone.com/zUBpsC, creating three separate variables with a `var_` prefix on the name of each:

```
declare -- var_an_arg="some-value"
declare -- var_another_arg="another-value"
declare -- var_third_arg="three"
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `: "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"`? Seeing the values when using `set -v`?

Comment: Thank you! Your input has certainly given me a lot to digest. Question, what does the pipe mean here at `re='^(|` ?

Comment: @BenjaminW., yup, it's to show values when debugging; they show up with `set -x` too, which I'm using in the ideone.com sandbox links.

Comment: @joliver, the `|` is so we can match an empty string; so we're matching either nothing at all, or at least one non-`=` character followed by a space.

Comment: you got my upvote and rec that OP accepts this answer; I swear on a stack of [DairyQ Triple Flamethrowers](https://www.dairyqueen.com/en-us/menu/flamethrower-stackburger/?size=triple) that my browser was only showing your `Associative Array` answer when I posted my (somewhat duplicate) answer

Comment: @markp-fuso, very believable, it's the one I built first :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Charles Duffy! Maybe it's something specific with the bash version I'm using `5.2.2(1)-release`, but the while condition would fail and `vars` would be empty. I had to replace `(|[^=]* )` with `([^=]* )?` and so the expression I used is: `^([^=]* )?([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]+)=([^[:space:]]+)( (.*))?$`

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable implementation, and I've updated the answer to use it. It may be not the bash version but the platform you're running on that controls legality here: the regex implementation bash uses is provided by the local operating system's standard C library.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- OP understands all the issues outlined by Charles Duffy but still wants standalone variables
- all variables names to be uppercased
- hyphens (`-`) converted to underscores (`_`)
- neither variable names nor the associated values contain embedded white space

One `bash` idea using namerefs:

```
unset newarg AN_ARG ANOTHER_ARG 2>/dev/null
STRING="/something an-arg=some-value another-arg=another-value"

read -ra list <<< "${STRING}"                                   # read into an array; each space-delimited item is a new entry in the array

#typeset -p list                                                # uncomment to display contents of the list[] array

regex='[^[:space:]]+=[^[:space:]]+'                             # search pattern: <var>=<value>, no embedded spaces in <var> nor <value>

for item in "${list[@]}"                                        # loop through items in list[] array
do
    if [[ "${item}" =~ $regex ]]                                # if we have a pattern match (<var>=<val>) then ...
    then
        IFS="=" read -r ndx val <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"        # split on '=' and read into variables ndx and val
        declare -nu newarg="${ndx//-/_}"                        # convert '-' to '_' and assign uppercased ndx to nameref 'newarg'
        newarg="${val}"                                         # assign val to newarg
    fi
done
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p AN_ARG ANOTHER_ARG
declare -- AN_ARG="some-value"
declare -- ANOTHER_ARG="another-value"
```

**NOTE:**

- once the `for` loop processing has completed, accessing the new variables will require some foreknowledge of the new variables' names
- using an associative array to manage the list of new variables makes post `for` loop accessing quite a bit easier (eg, the new variable names are simply the indices of the associative array)

Comment: The "word-split the strings then process them individually" approach is more robust than the one I took; I feel silly for doing something more complex. (OTOH, I do advise anyone considering this answer to think hard about the security implications of failing to prefix the generated names; if those names come from a less-trusted source than the code consuming them, they could be used for a lot of mischief).